# Access a control in another project's class from c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

In my Javascript I am accessing the class from a referenced project here:

```
<object id="class1" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom:10px;" height="48"
 classid="CLSID:50579BBE-03F5-4867-9D07-96BCBE2A0479" width="137">
<param name="BorderStyle" value="2"/> 
</object>
```

How can I access this javascript object from the c# code behind this javascript?

Comment: This is a example of usercontrol : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/jayendra/how-to-create-user-control-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: I have re-worded the question